# How to call a function that's inside a list?

Tags: scheme

I have a list of functions `flist` that receive 1 argument. I am trying to call the first function and pass `1` as an argument to it:

```
((car flist) 1)
```

And then I get:

```
 expected: pair? given: #<procedure:hash2>
```

I also tried:

```
(((car flist) 1))
```

But then I get another error:

```
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like `flist` is the `hash2` function instead of a list whose first element is `hash2`. Post the code that creates `flist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your function list wasn't properly built. For example, this works:

```
(define flist (list sin cos tan))
((car flist) 1)
=> 0.8414709848078965
```